# Migration to netstandard2.0 - CS0246: 'ExportAttribute' could not be found

Tags: migration, nuget-package, .net-standard-2.0

When I try to migrate to the
`<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`

I have error
`error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExportAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

here

```
 [Export( typeof( IViewModelRepositoryFactory ) )]
internal sealed class ViewModelRepositoryFactory : IViewModelRepositoryFactory
{
    private readonly IViewModelFactory[] _viewModelFactories;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ViewModelRepositoryFactory( [ImportMany] IViewModelFactory[] viewModelFactories )
```

How to fix it - looks like I need some nuget package ?

Inside what nuget I can found netstandard2.0 version for ExportAttribute ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use latest [System.ComponentModel.Composition](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Composition/) nuget package

for example add this to your csproj file

```
  <ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" Version="4.7.0" />
```